# Replicate an excel session, memory and all

Tags: vba, powershell, excel

I know how to open a new instance of excel. That's not what this is about. This has more to do with objects stored in memory and creating new instances of excel with the objects already stored.
A program called Numerix lets you store object in memory and call those objects (inside or outside of code). I need to have the same objects stored in several different instances of excel. 
Currently I have something that opens several instances of excel and stores the objects in each separately. 
I'm wondering if it is possible to store the objects in 1 instance of excel, then replicate that instance creating multiple instances of excel with those objects already in memory.

Let me know if you need further clarification. 
(It is not too important what language this is accomplished in. I'm really only familiar with C#, C++, vba and powershell)

Comment: I'm beginning to think that I have misunderstood the question. You want to do this within an Excel workbook as vba?

Comment: @EBGreen I haven't been terribly clear. My goal is to create another excel session with same things stored in memory as the first one. (this could be done through vba or something else.)  Does that make any more sense?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive that I understand all of your needs, but if I do understand then I think you could do it by using Export-CLIXML to store the base Excel object with whatever objects it holds in memory as a file. Then use Import-CLIXML to create as many duplicate objects as you want. This has the advantage that your "Golden Object" can be reconstituted to the same state across multiple PS sessions.

Alternatively I have not looked at Excel objects for this specifically, but they probably have a .Clone() method that would let you create a new one that is identical to your original in memory only.

Comment: Ya I'm afraid this solution isn't going to work, simply because I cannot pipe the excel objects back to excel.
.Clone() I've look into it a little bit and you can clone worksheets and workbooks, but not excel sessions with whatever they have stored in memory. :(
Thanks though.

Comment: Yes, as far as I know within the excel application API itself there is no good way to clone objects. From outside the API powershell can clone the objects, but you can't use that to expose them to VBA code running inside excel.

Comment: Hmmm, well it seems like my goals may not be possible. Thanks for your time. If you think of anything new be sure to let me know.